# Allow directory listing only for a IP

Tags: .htaccess, directory-listing

I've activated directory listing with this line in the .htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
```

How can I limit this to only one IP address with having access to all files/directories for everyone (every IP)?

Answer (score 3):

Not tested:

```
allow from all
Options -Indexes
<Files *>
deny from all
allow from 195.112.15.4
Options +Indexes
</Files>
```

This way the `Options +Indexes` will be valid only for IP `195.112.15.4`

Comment: I knew that snippet but doesn't work for me. I'm not able to access files with a different IP.
I just like to disallow Directory Listening

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but as I have just found something that seems to work, I've decided to share it here.

Adding this seems to do the trick:

```
<Files .>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny From All
   Allow From 195.112.15.4
</Files>
```

Comment: I know this is old as well but it's useful for development environment, I shared my webserver to public but I don't want them to browse my content, so this is very useful. Don't try the below one (didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got working for me, this is the .htaccess inside the folder I don't want everyone to be able to list, but if I give them a link to a file inside it, I want anyone (all) to be able to download the link.

```
allow from all
Options -Indexes

<Files *>
   deny from all
   allow from all  
   Options -Indexes
</Files>

<Files .>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny From All
   Allow From xx.xx.xx.xx
   # put the IP you want to allow indexing for above here
   Options +Indexes
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

tested 
supposing "index.html" is the one configured as your DirectoryIndex, and XX.XX.XX.XX is your IP address, simple put these lines:

```
<FilesMatch "index.html"> 
    Order deny,allow 
    Deny from all 
    allow from  XX.XX.XX.XX  
</FilesMatch>
```